# BroadcastChannel Event Not Received Across Different Browsers or Devices

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, cross-browser, broadcast-channel

the script itself works, but unfortunately only if it is in the same browser. if i have opened the page overlay.html on another device or browser i do not receive any event from the index page. as soon as i have opened overlay.html in the same browser but another tab it works

this is my script so far.

i would be very happy if someone could help me with my problem

```
<!-- /index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>TTS-Application Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="dataForm">
      <label for="textInput">Text:</label>
      <input type="text" id="textInput" name="textValue" />
      <button type="button" onclick="sendPing(document.getElementById('textInput').value)">
        Send to overlay
      </button>
    </form>
    <br />

    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='overlay.html'">
      Go to overlay.html
    </button>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <script>
      const channel = new BroadcastChannel("my_channel");
      function sendPing(audioSource) {
        console.log("Envoi du ping depuis index.html");
        channel.postMessage({ type: "ping", data: audioSource });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<!-- overlay.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Browser Overlay</title>
    <style>
        #randomText {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<div class="response"></div>
<body>
    <audio class="tts-audio" id="tts-audio"></audio>
    <div id="audioPlaceholder"></div>

    <script>
        const channel = new BroadcastChannel('my_channel');
        channel.onmessage = (event) => {
            console.log("Content of the input in index.html : " + event.data.data);
        };

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `but unfortunately only if it is in the same browser` - yes, it's never even implied that it works across multiple browsers let alone multiple devices!

Comment: Yes, MDN describes it as "The Broadcast Channel API allows basic communication between browsing contexts (that is, windows, tabs, frames, or iframes) and workers on the same origin.". It would be rather impressive if this somehow worked across devices without using something like a Websocket server.